Reading encoder output in MicroPython (Pi Pico) doesn't seem to work properly, any suggestions?
I've put together a pi pico, motor driver board, and a motor with 2 integrated hall effect encoders. The latter is from adafruit and the example code is written for Arduino. I've attempted to adapt this for MicroPython and my specific motor driver, but I just seem to get '0 RPM' when the motor is moving, or when I manually move the encoder wheel. I've been at this for a while and I'm at a loss, any clue where I might be going wrong?
from machine import Pin
import time
import PicoRobotics

# connect to the two encoder outputs
ENCODER_A = 24
ENCODER_B = 25

# ticks-to-RPM conversion factors
GEARING = 20
ENCODERMULT = 12

# encoder pins
encoder_a = Pin(ENCODER_A, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
encoder_b = Pin(ENCODER_B, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)

# initialise variables
RPM = 0
lastA = time.ticks_us()

def interruptA(pin):
    global lastA, RPM, motordir
    motordir = encoder_b.value()

    currA = time.ticks_us()
    if time.ticks_diff(currA, lastA) > 0:
        rev = time.ticks_diff(currA, lastA)
        rev = 1.0 / rev
        rev *= 1000000
        rev *= 60
        rev /= GEARING
        rev /= ENCODERMULT
        RPM = rev
    lastA = currA
   
encoder_a.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_RISING, handler=interruptA)

def printRPM():
    print(int(RPM), " RPM")

def loop():
    board = PicoRobotics.KitronikPicoRobotics()
    directions = ["f","r"]
    board.motorOn(1, "f", 20)
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        printRPM()        

loop()



Does the interrupt triggered at all? setup a LED to toggle when the interrupt is triggered for debugging. 2) where do you define the global variable motordir? 3) 1.0 / rev * 1000000 is just 1000000 / rev, it will be more readable code with RPM = 1000000 / rev * 60 / GEARING / ENCODERMULT.

